# mysql query to generate weekly report store wise

Tags: mysql

visitor trend between two date,result in weekly manner..

Comment: This question is very unclear. Please add more detail, including sample table data etc..

Comment: [well-written questions](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) will include [concise, complete sample code](http://sscce.org/). For DB questions, this means table create statements & an `INSERT` statement for sample data. If possible, DB query questions should include example results.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer your question without a little more context, but have a look at the datetime functions in MySQL:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week

A simple `GROUP BY WEEK(datefld)` would take care of the "weekly" aspect of your question, the statistical/mathematical functions you need depend on your specific case:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html